# How to access hidden column values

Tags: jquery, .net, datatables

Work on Asp.net mvc5. To hide jQuery DataTables column I used the syntax below, it works perfectly but after hiding the column I cannot access selected rows hidden column values.

**To hide column**

```
$('.tbl').dataTable({
            "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "oTableTools": {
                "aButtons": [],
                "sRowSelect": "single"
            },
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bSort": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
                "visible": false
            }

            ]

        });
```

**To get the selected rows**

```
var oTT = TableTools.fnGetInstance('tbl'); // Get Table instance
var sRow = oTT.fnGetSelected(); // Get Selected Item From Table
var hiddelColumnValue=$.trim(sRow[0].cells[10].innerHTML.toString());
```

There is no value in `hiddelColumnValue`. How to get selected rows hidden column value in jQuery DataTables?

Is it possible to retrieve hidden column values from jQuery DataTables?

Answer (score 1):

For DataTables 1.10 and TableTools:

Assign ID `tbl` to your table instead of class because `fnGetInstance()` requires table ID when string is provided, see [API](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/api) reference.

```js
var oTT = TableTools.fnGetInstance('tbl'); // Get Table instance
var sRow = oTT.fnGetSelected();

// Iterate over selected rows
$('#tbl').DataTable().rows(sRow).every(function(){
   // Get row data
   var data = this.data();   

   // Log 11th column data
   console.log(data[10]);    
});
```

See [`rows().every()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows%28%29.every%28%29) and [`row().data()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.data%28%29) API methods for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I face some problem api() not supported,i install jquery table from nuget  <package id="jquery.datatables" version="1.10.10" targetFramework="net451" /> is there any way with out api()

Comment: @shamim, sorry there was an error in the code which is now corrected.